# how to write execsql() in android

Tags: android

how to write execsql in database adapter for

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE DeviceDetails SET devicename = ? WHERE uuid = ?",
    new String[] {
      edittext.getText().toString(), 
      c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"))
    });
```

i did in database like as follows

```
public void select(String query) throws SQLException {
   db.execSQL(query, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    Cursor c = sqliteDB.rawQuery("UPDATE "+ TABLE_NAME + " SET "+ WHAT_YOU_WANT_TO_SET + " = "+WITH_WHAT_VALUE+ " WHERE " + WHAT_YOU_WANT_TO_MATCH + " = \""+WITH_WHAT+"\"", null);
```